# Does "kubectl delete pod <name> --grace-period=60" have effect only on containers that have code to shut down graciously?

Tags: kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

The documentation is not clear on this aspect.  My containers do not handle the SIGTERM and SIGKILL signals, so I have no code that delays the shut down.  Whenever I type the command in the subject line in PowerShell, the container goes away instantly, never transition into the "Terminating" state.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a read of [the official document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods) covering this.

I assume this is the expected behaviour, your containers terminate instantly as you have no code to handle the termination.